# How can Implement custom repository in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am using **Nest JS** v8 and **Type ORM** v8.1.2. I want to create custom repository such as following sample and add custom methods to it. but the version of Type ORM doesn't support this feature.

```
@EntityRepository(User)
 export class UserRepository extends Repository<User>
      customFind() {}
 }
```

Tip: Actually i want make a generic repository.

How can i implementing it?

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Typeorm current version doesn't support this feature, you can try this method to create your custom repository

```
@Injectable()
export class UserRepository {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
    private readonly repository: BaseRepository<UserEntity>,
  ) {}

  get instance() {
    return this.repository;
  }
}
```

at `^0.2.45` version

```
@EntityRepository(UserEntity)
export class UserRepository extends BaseRepository<UserEntity> {}
```

note: i'm using BaseRepository in [typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked](https://github.com/odavid/typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked)

Answer (score 0):

Yes that can be done. With custom repositories, the DI is not managed by Nestjs. I learned that the hard way. The trick is to use `getCustomRepository`.
This is how you would do it

```
@EntityRepository(SomeEntity)
export class SomeCustomRepository extends Repository<SomeEntity> {
 customFind() {}
}


@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

  async doStuff() {
    const repository = getCustomRepository(
        SomeCustomRepository
      );
    repository.doStuff()
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not use @EntityRepository decorator as it is deprecated